# Silencing Factory Girl logging

Tags: ruby, tdd, rspec, cucumber, factory-bot

Just to clear the air, I am not some cruel factory master trying to silence working ladies.  I am having a very annoying problem where when using Thoughtbot's factory girl in my specs, every time Factory.create(:foo) is used, the newly created ActiveRecord model instance is logged to the console.  This makes looking at my console output more difficult to visually filter out all of the extra logging.  Is there a setting somewhere or a flag that can be set that will silence this extra logging?

Below is a small example of my rspec output.  The '.' at the beginning of each line, in this case, is a successful test.

```
loading autotest/rspec
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.2.9/bin/spec --autospec spec/publisher_spec.rb -O spec/spec.opts 
#<Event id: nil, oid: "mainEvent1", name: "Main Event", short_name: "mainevent", time_zone: "PST", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, draft: true, draft_origin_id: nil, draft_deleted: false>
#<Event id: nil, oid: "mainEvent1", name: "Main Event", short_name: "mainevent", time_zone: "PST", created_at: "2009-11-18 19:11:56", updated_at: "2009-11-18 19:11:56", draft: true, draft_origin_id: 3, draft_deleted: false>
#<Event id: nil, oid: "bumbershoo", name: "Bumbershoot", short_name: "bumbershoot", time_zone: "PST", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, draft: true, draft_origin_id: nil, draft_deleted: false>
#<Notification id: nil, oid: "8P93CNEcl0", event_id: 3, name: "Penut Butter Jelly Time", url: nil, type: "Alert", priority: 10, last_displayed: "2009-11-16 19:11:54", format: nil, content: "IT'S PENUT BUTTER JELLY TIME.  WHERE YOU AT? WHERE ...", image: nil, is_active: true, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, updated_by: nil, image_file_name: nil, image_content_type: nil, image_file_size: nil, image_updated_at: nil, draft: true, draft_origin_id: nil, draft_deleted: false>
#<Notification id: nil, oid: "8P93CNEcl0", event_id: 3, name: "Penut Butter Jelly Time", url: nil, type: "Alert", priority: 10, last_displayed: "2009-11-16 19:11:54", format: nil, content: "IT'S PENUT BUTTER JELLY TIME.  WHERE YOU AT? WHERE ...", image: nil, is_active: true, created_at: "2009-11-18 19:11:57", updated_at: "2009-11-18 19:11:57", updated_by: nil, image_file_name: nil, image_content_type: nil, image_file_size: nil, image_updated_at: nil, draft: true, draft_origin_id: 3, draft_deleted: false>
.#<Event id: nil, oid: "mainEvent1", name: "Main Event", short_name: "mainevent", time_zone: "PST", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, draft: true, draft_origin_id: nil, draft_deleted: false>
#<Event id: nil, oid: "bumbershoo", name: "Bumbershoot", short_name: "bumbershoot", time_zone: "PST", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, draft: true, draft_origin_id: nil, draft_deleted: false>
.#<Event id: nil, oid: "mainEvent1", name: "Main Event", short_name: "mainevent", time_zone: "PST", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, draft: true, draft_origin_id: nil, draft_deleted: false>
.#<Event id: nil, oid: "mainEvent1", name: "Main Event", short_name: "mainevent", time_zone: "PST", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, draft: true, draft_origin_id: nil, draft_deleted: false>
.#<Event id: nil, oid: "mainEvent1", name: "Main Event", short_name: "mainevent", time_zone: "PST", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, draft: true, draft_origin_id: nil, draft_deleted: false>
```

I have picked over my specs many times to see if I have a "puts foo.inspect" anywhere, and I do not.  This happens for all of my rspec and cucumber tests using autotest and normally running tests individually.

Here is my [factories.rb](http://gist.github.com/238342) file that relates to the above output.  Note: there is some minor fanciness happening in my factories.rb.

[Update:2009-11-20] Just trying to keep this fresh, and see if someone else may have any ideas.

Comment: You cruel capitalist factory master!

Comment: Update: For some reason this is no longer an issue.  See if you wait long enough and do nothing, things fix themselves.  I wish I knew what changed that remedied the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Can you give some more details on where exactly you're seeing the logging lines? Are you running `rake spec`? Can you copy/paste some example output?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how or why, but this problem has resolved its self.  I can only speculate that it was an update to Factory Girl or rspec.  Maybe I removed some logging in my code.  I can't be sure.